# How to swap images dynamically - wrong image showing

Tags: android, android-view

I need to change the source of an ImageView dynamically. I have a whole bunch of them with the same names, stored in their different dpi directories (drawable-hdpi etc) under res/. For this I've been using ImageView's setImageResource() and passing it a value from an array of resource IDs I've created at runtime like so:

```
decorations = new int[]{                
    R.drawable.bird1,       
R.drawable.flower2,
R.drawable.bird3,
..etc};
```

Anyway, for some reason, the 6th image gets corrupted into an alternative image used for other things, not one in the resources list.

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a corrupt/incorrect image or the image was in the wrong directory or something. Still, strange that it decided to just display the next image in the directory rather than just crashing with an Exception or something.